# Prove that a nonzero integer p is prime if and only if the ideal (p) is maximal in Z.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I know that if (p) is maximal then Z/(p) is a field which implies its an integral domain which then implies that (p) is a prime ideal and p is prime. I'm having trouble going the forward direction assuming that p is prime and then showing it's a prime ideal.

Comment: Use Euclid's lemma.

Comment: How would that help me?

Comment: If $a,b\in\Bbb Z$ and $ab\in (p)$, then $p\mid ab$, so $p\mid a$ or $p\mid b$, hence $a\in (p)$ or $b\in (p)$.

Answer (score 2):

In general, if $(a)$ is an ideal of $\mathbb Z$ then the ideals contained between $(a)$ and $\mathbb Z$ correspond to the *divisors* of $a$. For example, if $a=10$ then $\mathbb Z=(1)\supset(5)\supset(10)$ and $\mathbb Z=(1)\supset(2)\supset(10)$. This is a consequence of the more general fact that $(a)\supseteq(b)\iff a\mid b$. Now what are the divisors of a prime integer?

Comment: I haven't notice that $(1)=\mathbb Z...$ :)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $ $ Notice that for principal ideals: $\ \rm\color{#0a0}{contains} = \color{#c00}{divides}$, $ $ i.e.  $(a)\supseteq (b)\iff a\mid b,\,$ thus

$\qquad\quad\begin{eqnarray} (p)\,\text{ is maximal} 
&\iff&\!\!\ (p)\, \text{ has no proper } \,{\rm\color{#0a0}{container}}\,\ (d)\\
&\iff&\  p\ \ \text{ has no proper}\,\ {\rm\color{#c00}{divisor}}\,\ d\\
&\iff&\  p\ \ \text{ is irreducible}\\
\end{eqnarray}$

Comment: Is $(p)$ has no proper container $(d)$ equivalent to say $(p)$ has no proper elements $(d)$?

Comment: @AnneliseToft $\ $ What do you mean by "$(p)$ has no proper elements $(d)$"? $\ \ $

Comment: I dont understand the english term 'container', is there another way to express the term?

Comment: @AnneliseToft Read that as "divisor". Bill is saying that containment equals division for principal ideals.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff pero que va a pasar con ese paso? con esa equivalencia? no me estaría saltando un paso importante?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Ah no, ya me di cuenta que no pasa nada, por la igualdad haha

Comment: @AnneliseToft $\ (a)\,$ contains $(b)$ means that $(a)\supseteq (b).\,$ The idea is that that a nontrivial  ("proper") container $(d)$ of $(a)$ corresponds to a nontrivial divisor $d$ of $a$ using "contains = divides" in a PID, since $\ (1)\supsetneq (a) \supsetneq (d)\iff 1\mid a\mid d\,$ *properly* (i.e $\,a\nmid 1,\, d\nmid a).\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque this question was in my exam and I prove it as you did (well almost, I edit it a bit and then I post it here), but my professor told me (today) the proof was WRONG because I didn't use the hypothesis of maximal and primes (he said something like that). Please tell me he is crazy and wrong, and your proof is perfect .

Comment: @BillDubuque https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2358246/p-is-prime-iff-langle-p-rangle-is-maximal-euclidean-ring this is the question

Comment: @Annelise That looks fine, assuming that you already covered the standard proof of irreducible $\iff$ prime in PIDs. What *precisely* was the critique you received?

Comment: @BillDubuque First he told me: 'you must prove first this $\Arrow $ direction and then the opposite direction ', and I was like wtf? a proof can be proved using just $\iff$ signs

Comment: @Annelise Which particular $\iff$ do you refer to?

Comment: @BillDubuque all of them, since (p) is maximal to p is prime

Comment: @Annelise That's puzzling, the first and third are by definition of maximal and irreducible, and the second is by contains = divides.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62255/discussion-between-annelise-toft-and-bill-dubuque).

Answer (score 1):

One proof would be to use the fact that $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is an integral domain iff it is a field.  It is a basic fact from number theory that the units in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ are exactly the numbers coprime to $n$ and the non units are always zero divisors $\mod n$.