# $p\in \mathbb Z$ is prime if and only if $\langle p\rangle$ is maximal.

Tags: abstract-algebra

$p\in \mathbb Z$ is prime if and only if $\langle p\rangle$ is maximal.

Could someone give me a hint to prove it. please?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/772115/227902

Comment: A more general approach would be to prove that an ideal $I$ is maximal $\iff$ the quotient $R/I$ is a field.  This is an important theorem, and can be applied here; indeed $\mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z}$ is a field.

Comment: @KajHansen yes but at this moment I'm just interested about the particular case :)

Comment: @AnneliseToft what have you tried?

Comment: @Annelise Toft: As an experienced MSE participant, you are expected to make an effort to state the question unambigously. In your initial post, no ring was mentioned, so a reader would have had to guess your intention. As you can see, an edit was needed, and was supplied by Pedro Tamaroff.

Comment: @Annelise Toft: Do you already know that all ideals of $\mathbb{Z}$ are principal?

Comment: @quasi yes I know

Comment: @Annelise Toft: Then the rest is straightforward. First suppose the ideal $(p)$ is contained in the proper ideal $I$. Write $I=(n)$ and argue that $n$ is a divisor of $p$. Deduce that $I=(p)$. For the converse, assume $I=(n)$ is maximal. Then $n$ must be a nonzero nonunit. Suppose $n$ is not prime. Then letting $n = ab$, where $a,b$ are nonzero nonunits, argue that $(a)$ is a proper ideal strictly containing $(n)$, contradiction.

Comment: @quasi will the proof have a lot of changes if it were not Z?

Comment: @Annelise Toft: No changes if the ring is a PID (principal ideal domain), i.e., an integral domain such that all ideals are principal.

Comment: @quasi it is an euclidean ring

Comment: @Annelise Toft: If an integral domain is a Euclidean ring, then it's a PID.

Comment: @quasi an euclidian ring is a euclidian domain

Comment: @quasi which is a pair (A,f), where A is an integral domain, so no changes at all, right?

Comment: @Annelist Toft: Then it's a PID, so no problem. Once you know it's a PID, then for this problem, you no longer need the Division Algorithm.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62182/discussion-between-annelise-toft-and-quasi).