# $p$ is prime iff $\langle p\rangle$ is maximal (euclidean ring)

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory, ideals, euclidean-domain

Let $\mathbb E$ an euclidian ring and $p\in \mathbb E$. Prove $p$ is prime iff $\langle p\rangle$ is maximal.

Proof:

As $\mathbb E$ is an euclidian ring (euclidean domain), then it is a PID (By Fraleigh theorem).

$ $ Notice that for principal ideals: $\ {contains} = \ {divides}$, $ $ i.e.  $(a)\supseteq (b)\iff a\mid b,\,$ thus

$\qquad\quad\begin{eqnarray} (p)\,\text{ is maximal} 
&\iff&\!\!\ (p)\, \text{ has no proper } \,{{container}}\,\ (d), (d)\neq(1)\\
&\iff&\  p\ \ \text{ has no nonunit proper}\,\ {{divisor}}\,\ d\\
&\iff&\  p\ \ \text{ is irreducible}\\
&\iff&\  p\ \ \text{ is prime}\\\end{eqnarray}$

Note: this proof was based on Bill Dubuque's proof [in another post for the case of $\mathbb{Z}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/772112/prove-that-a-nonzero-integer-p-is-prime-if-and-only-if-the-ideal-p-is-maximal).

Is the proof correct??

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: @Weaam it's pretty similar, I actually followed his proof, but my proof has little details that requires for an euclidean ring and I posted it because I wanted to be 100% sure that it is correct.

Comment: @AnneliseToft Thanks for the edit.

Comment: Just one thing, you have to prove that in a Euclidean domain $p$ irreducible $\iff$ $p$ prime.

Comment: @Xam how to prove it?

Comment: Use the euclidean function to create an euclidean algorithm. It's very similar to the case of $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @Xam hmm and is the proof incomplete if I don't prove the little step: p irreducible iff p prime?

Comment: Yeah, it's incomplete. Though shouldn't be difficult to prove.

Comment: @Xam you said this proof is incomplete ( because the proof of p prime iff p irreducible is needed) but can I argue that the proof is trivial and therefore I  didn't see the need to mention it in the whole proof?

Comment: @Xam I don't need to prove $p$ irreducible $\iff p$ prime in a Euclidean domain, I need to prove it in a PID. Am I correct?

Comment: @t.Anne well you can  prove it in a PID so it would be more general to prove it in this context: you don't need the euclidean division for that. It's even true in a UFD if I'm not mistaken, which PID's are.